# How is this the $b_n$ in this series? (Alternating Series Test)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am using the Alternating Series Test for this series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n+1)\pi}{1+\sqrt n}$$

Why is my $b_n$ this?:

$$\frac {1}{1+\sqrt n} $$

I dont understand what makes the $sin(n+1)\pi$ all of a sudden go away, since from my understanding I am used to stating my $a_n$ as being either $(-1)^n$ or $(-1)^{n-1}$. But then in this series I dont even see any negatives, let alone anything being raised to the power of $n$. So, all in all, why is my $b_n$ what it is?

Comment: every term in the series is 0 since sin($n\pi$)=0

Comment: How can I do that? Wouldn't it make a difference that the \pi is on the outside? Because for example when I try n=1 and n=2 I get both positive answers for $\sin (n+1)\pi$

Comment: perhaps you didn;t copy the problem right and it was $\cos$, not $\sin$ ?

Comment: Nope exactly correct checked it twice

Comment: The question is whether $\sin(n+1)\pi$ means $\sin((n+1)\pi)$ or $(\sin(n+1))\pi$.

Comment: Kind of yes because then that would help justify my $b_n$

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes more sense to me if you used $\cos$, not $\sin$. 
Consider $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n+1)\pi}{1+\sqrt n}$.

$\cos(n+1)\pi$ does not just go away. If $n$ is odd then $n+1$ is even and 
$\cos(n+1)\pi = 1$. If If $n$ is even then $n+1$ is odd and 
$\cos(n+1)\pi = -1$. So the series becomes $-1+\frac12-\frac1{1+\sqrt{2}}+\frac1{1+\sqrt{3}} \cdots$

This should explain why $b_n= |\frac{\cos(n+1)\pi}{1+\sqrt n}|=\frac {1}{1+\sqrt n}$.